# NextJS getStaticProps() never called

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am making a simple website and I would like to fetch data from an API and display it on my component.
The problem is that the `getStaticProps()` method is never called.

Here is the code of the component :

```js
import React from "react";
import {GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType} from "next";

type RawProject = {
    owner: string;
    repo: string;
    link: string;
    description: string;
    language: string;
    stars: number;
    forks: number;
}

function Projects({projects}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
    console.log(projects);
    return (
        <section id="projects" className="bg-white p-6 lg:p-20">
            <h1 className="sm:text-4xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-gray-900 pb-6 text-center">
                Quelques de mes projets
            </h1>
            {/*
            <div className="container px-5 mx-auto">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                    {rawProjects.map((project: RawProject) => (
                        <ProjectCard
                            title={project.repo}
                            language={project.language}
                            description={project.description}
                            imageUrl="https://dummyimage.com/720x400"
                            repoUrl={project.link}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            */}
        </section>
    );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    console.log("getStaticProps()");
    const res = await fetch("https://gh-pinned-repos-5l2i19um3.vercel.app/?username=ythepaut");
    const projects: RawProject[] = await res.json();
    return !projects ? {notFound: true} : {
        props: {projects: projects},
        revalidate: 3600
    };
}

export default Projects;
```

The full code can be found here : https://github.com/ythepaut/webpage/tree/project-section

I am not sure if the problem is caused by the fact that I use typescript, or that I use a custom `_app.tsx`

I tried the solutions from :

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11328
- [How to make Next.js getStaticProps work with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078245/how-to-make-next-js-getstaticprops-work-with-typescript)

but I couldn't make it work.

Could someone help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getStaticProps()` is only allowed in pages.

Your code at the moment is :

```
import Hero from "../sections/Hero";
import Contact from "../sections/Contact";
import Projects from "../sections/Projects"; // you cannot call getStaticProps() in this componenet

function HomePage(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-50">
            <Hero />
            <Projects />
            <Contact />
        </div>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Instead call `getStaticProps()`  inside `index.tsx` and pass the props to the component something like this ::

```
import Hero from "../sections/Hero";
import Contact from "../sections/Contact";
import Projects from "../sections/Projects"; 

function HomePage({data}): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-50">
            <Hero />
            <Projects data={data} />
            <Contact />
        </div>
    );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    console.log("getStaticProps()");
    const res = await fetch("https://gh-pinned-repos-5l2i19um3.vercel.app/?username=ythepaut");
    const projects: RawProject[] = await res.json();
    return !projects ? {notFound: true} : {
        props: {projects: projects},
        revalidate: 3600
    };
}
export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 4):

Data fetching methods in NextJs like **getStaticProps** runs only on the server. Hence it **works only in pages**, not in a regular react component

Please Check their [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

For data fetching in **Normal Components**, You can only do **client-side Rendering**. NextJS recommends using this library [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)

According to their docs

> SWR is a strategy to first return the data from cache (stale), then send the fetch request (revalidate), and finally, come with the up-to-date data.

Answer (score 2):

### **You can only use `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` in Next.js pages**

I checked your project and saw that your `Project.tsx` was in a component folder, but it needs to be in `pages` folder for those functions to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In pages folder you must export getStaticProps too

Example

```js
export { default } from '../../games/tebak-kata/game';
export { getStaticPaths } from '../../games/tebak-kata/game';
export { getStaticProps } from '../../games/tebak-kata/game';
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar bad experience because of bad service worker implementation, if you found it works with "Empty Cache and Hard Reload", you should check your service-worker code, you may don't want to cache any pages.
[image]