# Unable to get data from api using Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Next js and i am trying to fetching record via api, but right now i am getting following error

```
"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
```

Here is my code (components/Blog.jsx)

```
export default function Blog({ people }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {people.map(person => (
          <>
            <h1>{person.name}</h1>
            <h2>Website: {person.website}</h2>
            Email: <code>{person.email}</code>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const people = await response.json();
  
    return {
      props: {
        people
      }
    };
  };
```

Comment: If that component is located in `/components/Blog.jsx` then it's not a page component. That means `getStaticProps` will not work, Next.js data fetching methods like `getSaticProps` only work in page components. See [NextJS getStaticProps() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075289/nextjs-getstaticprops-never-called).

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix is to before you return your Blog() function you do something like this

```
people = people || []
```

This will make people have a default so that it cannot be undefined when you try to map it

Comment: where should i use this ?

And right now i am trying to fetch data by creating "component" , so is this correct way or should i create "page" and move my code inside that page inside "page" folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have NOT fetch data from API yet. Pre-define data is empty array if not get data. Try this

```
export default function Blog({ people = [] }) {
.....
```

I hope this work.

Comment: You can `console.log(response);`  in `getStaticProps` function to check your data

Answer (score 0):

After reading your problem, I understood that It happens either because of the undefined value of people

```
export default function Blog({ people }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {people.map(person => (
          <>
            <h1>{person.name}</h1>
            <h2>Website: {person.website}</h2>
            Email: <code>{person.email}</code>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export const getStaticProps = async () => {
try{
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const people = await response.json();
    return { props: { people} }
  }catch{
    return { props: {  } }
  }
  
  };
```

Comment: still getting same error 

should i use "components" for fetch data or "pages" for fetch data , in other words my current code is inside "components" folder, Is this correct process ? or should i move my code to "pages" folder (create seprate page ) and fetch data

Comment: As per my experience, pages is better to call the getStaticProps function. Components section for Card, Container, Button like modules and pass response by props.

export async function getStaticProps() {
        let Data=  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        console.log({Data}); 
        let sample= await Data.json();
        return { props: {sample } }
}

Answer (score 0):

As far the documentation said, we can't use `getStaticProps` function in component level. We should use it only in a page. Read this section for better understanding https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#where-can-i-use-getstaticprops . And also be sure to initialize people as an empty array -> people = [] . Hope this logic solves your problem.