# Unable to use page data in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am new in nextjs,created "Blog.js" page (inside "page" folder) for fetch data via api,Whenever i open page in browser then data is displaying but whenever i call that page in index.js then displaying following error

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
```

Here is my code in "Data.js" (inside page folder)

```
import react from "react";

function Data(props)
{
    console.warn("data",props);
    return <div className="abc">
    {
    props.data.map(data=>(
            <div>
                <a>{data.title}</a>
                {props.title}
            </div>
        ))
 } 

</div>
}
Data.getInitialProps=async function()
{
    const res= await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const data =await res.json();
    return {
        data
    }
}
export default Data
```

And after import, i am using following code for use "Data",Where i am wrong ?

```
<Data />
```

Comment: That looks fine. What do you mean you're using <Data/>? You would never use it anywhere, it lives in a Next.js pages folder and you simply visit the URL /Data. You can't import it and use it somewhere and hope it works, the getInitialProps API is only for next.js to consume. If you try to mount that component yourself passing no props, you would get the above error because.. data is undefined, and data.map wouldn't work. Try pasting that into a code sandbox. <Data/> receives no props, thus error. Go to /Data in the browser... and next will pass it props.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: let me explain , if i use above page as "localhost:3000/blogs" then its working fine, but i want to import and use above in "index.js" so thats why i used "<Data>" , so that i can get "data/response" from "Data.js", Hope you understand my point

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: Please tell should i use "import getStaticProps  " in index.js ? thats why i am getting above error ? am i right or wrong ?

Comment: It would help if you abstracted the data fetch logic and rendering logic in a separate file. Reuse that file on the Index and Blog page.

Comment: @omui: Kindly tell me one thing , if my code is working with "http:localhost:3000/blog" then how can i use direct in my index.js ?

How to import "gestaticprops/getinitialprops" with page name in next js ?

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita  How can i import "staticprops" in nextjs ? i think thats something i missing

Comment: @Amit you don't need to import it. You only define it on the next.js page.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

Comment: @omi it means i just have to write "<Data /> ?

Suppose i have 4 section/modules in my index.js and i want to dynamic any one module (via api ) so thats why i put this question, hope you understand my point

Comment: @Amit you can not use the Blog page inside the Index page as a component. The blog page is dependent on the API response and when you import the Blog page as a component the getInitialProps function will not run. It is executed by the Next.js in the page life cycle. Hope I am able to explain.

Comment: @omi understand your point, so it means if i want to use data from api then i have to create "components" instead of "page" and then my data will fetch , am i right ? if yes then in that case my code will run ( import ....from component) or there will some change in my code (index.js) ?, am i right ?

Comment: @Amit You should abstract the data fetching logic into a utility. Use that utility in both the Index and Blog pages to fetch data inside getInitialProps. Import the Blog page inside Index and pass the props.

Comment: @omi: understand your point but what you mean by "pass the props", should i pass again ? means props will pass in "Blog.js" (inside component folder) so then i will import this to index.js page then ? should i use "<Blog />" or some other code ?

Comment: @Amit Yes, you should pass all required props from the Index page. The index page will also have data because we have fetched API inside getInitialProps in the Index page.

Comment: Welcome @Amit Please upvote my comments.

Comment: `getInitialProps` (and other Next.js data fetching methods) only work when they're used in a page component. See [NextJS getStaticProps() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075289/nextjs-getstaticprops-never-called). In your case you're using `Data` as a regular component from the `Index` page, meaning `getInitialProps` will not run in `Data`. Either fetch the data from the `Index` page and pass it down to `Data`, or fetch the data on the client-side in `Data`.