# How to use Hooks in components Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs(nextjs),And i am tyring to use "hooks" in functional components
Right now i am trying to fetch data via api but i am getting following error

```
TypeError: Trending is undefined
```

Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
const Trending = ({ Trending }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log({ Trending });
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div className="container Blog_page_sidebar">
          <div className="blog_details">
            <div className="blog_image">{Trending.title}</div>
            <div className="blog_heading"></div>
            <div className="blog_detail"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Trending;

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(
    `https://myurl/blogs`
  );
  const Trending = data;
  return {
    props: {
      Trending,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: what is inside data variable after api call, maybe api call returns undefined

Comment: @Alopwer: i checked the api , Api showing/return data

Comment: are you sure there is data property in the response? I think you can use just ```data``` without destructuring

Comment: @Alopwer: what is data "property" ? And what should i do for fetch response/data?

Comment: Instead of this: ```const { data } = await Axios.get(
    `https://myurl/blogs`
  );``` use this: ```const data = await Axios.get(
    `https://myurl/blogs`
  );```

Comment: Can you try changing `const { data }` on `const response`, then log the response using `console.log(response)` and show us the output?

Comment: @Alopwer: still i am getting same error

Comment: @User456 Actually i am working on "component" and use component in index.js file,In Console.log i am getting nothing/console.log not workig

Comment: `getStaticProps` only works in page components, it doesn't run in regular components. See [NextJS getStaticProps() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075289/nextjs-getstaticprops-never-called).

Answer (score 0):

If you want call API in useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
 const getData = async() => {
   try {
      const data = await axios.get(`https://myurl/blogs`);
      console.log('data is = ' , data);
      setData(data)
   }catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
 }
//call the inner function inside useEffect
 getData();

)} ,[])
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question

Comment: check axios and put the code in try and catch in getStaticProps make sure your getting data from api