# TypeScript error only with getStaticProps when I use GetStaticProps within a Next.js component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've having trouble isolating an error reported by TypeScript when I use the type GetStaticProps in my code. Without this, it works without issue. I'm confused why I'm seeing this error.

```
interface RowProps {
  id: number;
  created_at: Date;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

interface PageProps {
  lesson: RowProps;
}

interface PageParams extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  params: {
    id: string;
  }
}

// This code works perfectly:
// export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { id } }: PageParams) => {
//   const { data: lesson } = await supabase
//     .from("lesson")
//     .select("*")
//     .eq("id", id)
//     .single();

//   return {
//     props: {
//       lesson,
//     },
//   };
// };

// This code does not work and I don't know why:
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps, PageParams> = async ({
  params: { id },
}) => {
  const { data: lesson } = await supabase
    .from("lesson")
    .select("*")
    .eq("id", id)
    .single();

  return {
    props: {
      lesson,
    },
  };
};
```

I get an error that says:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'PageParams | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

After an entire day of trying to solve this, I'm simply at a total loss for what's going on.

Could anyone help me understand why I'm unable to destructure "id" so that I can use it directly in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Next.js getStaticProps work with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078245/how-to-make-next-js-getstaticprops-work-with-typescript)

Comment: No, my issue is w/the getStaticProps function, not the page component.

Answer (score 0):

You should not give the `getStaticProps` argument a type (you are giving it a `Props` type)

The `GetStaticProps` type already knows what argument it will recieve.

You gave the argument the following type:

```
interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}
```

This was probably done to add a type to `params.id`, but if you want to do that, you should pass a type parameter to `GetStaticProps`.

The `GetStaticProps` can take two type arguments (actually, it can take 3, but I don't know what the third one is for haha)

The first one is the props of your component, it is used to know what to return from the function.
The second one is the types of your parameters.

For you, the types should look like this:

```
interface PageProps {
  lesson: dbRecord;
}

interface PageParams {
  id: string;
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps, PageParams> = async ({
  params: { id }, // id will now have a string type
}) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I made a few changes to the question per your suggestions, but I'm still having trouble destructuring "id."

Comment: Take a look at my definition of `PageParams` vs your definition of `PageParams`, yours looks like this: `{params: {id: string}}`, mine looks like this: `{id: string}` There should also be no need to extend `ParsedUrlQuery`, or at least, not that I know.